# extendedCertificate's in PKCS7 / CMS

Tags: asn1, pkcs7

In [PKCS7 / CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652), for the signed-data content type, there's a CertifcateChoices field in the certicates field in SignedData that is a SET of CertificateChoices. CertificateChoices is defined thusly:

```
   CertificateChoices ::= CHOICE {
     certificate Certificate,
     extendedCertificate [0] IMPLICIT ExtendedCertificate,  -- Obsolete
     v1AttrCert [1] IMPLICIT AttributeCertificateV1,        -- Obsolete
     v2AttrCert [2] IMPLICIT AttributeCertificateV2,
     other [3] IMPLICIT OtherCertificateFormat }
```

AttributeCertificateV2 is defined as follows:

```
   AttributeCertificateV2 ::= AttributeCertificate
```

But where is `AttributeCertificate` defined? I did `Ctrl+F` in my browser for in RFC5652 (the RFC defining PKCS7 / CMS) and didn't find any useful results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined in 4.1 of [RFC3281](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3281.txt)

```
 AttributeCertificate ::= SEQUENCE {
             acinfo               AttributeCertificateInfo,
             signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
             signatureValue       BIT STRING
        }
```